# How to make NLog terminate application on fatal errors?

Tags: c#, fatal-error, nlog

Can I somehow set up an event handler for fatal errors in the code? I would like to terminate the application immediately if such an error happens, i.e. something like this:

```
void Fail(string format, params object[] args) {
  Logger.Fatal(format, args);
  Environment.Exit(-1);
}
```

However I would like this to happen automatically:

```
Logger.Fatal(...); // logs the error and invokes Environment.Exit(-1);
```

Is there a way to setup some kind of callback for all fatal errors or some configuration option for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 
you can do this using `MethodCall` target (see https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/MethodCall-target)

Here example:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    using System;

    public class MyClass
    {
        public static void HandleFatalEventLog(string level)
        {
            if(level.Equal("Fatal", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
            {
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And NLog.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target name="m" xsi:type="MethodCall" className="SomeNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly" methodName="HandleFatalEventLog">
            <parameter layout="${level}" />
        </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Fatal" writeTo="m" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

PS: But, I would not recommend this approach, logger should not shutdown application